# Why wrong casting of generics won't produce exception in java?

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
Map<Object, Object> map;
...
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
Object tmp = map.get("strings");
strings.addAll((List<String>) tmp);
```

It works fine if tmp is of type `List<String>`, but why the program won't produce exception if tmp is of type `List<Map>`?

Comment: Could you show us the code you have in mind while talking about the second part?

Comment: Sounds like this question is about [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/339699

Comment: @Amongalen ```List<Map> tmp; (List<String>) tmp;``` this cast would still work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cast to `List<String>` of an Object actually is a cast to `List`. At runtime String no longer is there. The IDE *did* warn about this. Later on when working with `strings` items a runtime exception may be expected.

Another thing, `List<Map>` misses generic parameters, and when used bare, like `List list`, the compiler reverts to non-generic interpretation, dropping all warning of generic type violations.

For your use-case: a kind of simple "variable" map with differently typed variables is problematic. Provide your own run-time type info, and maybe revert to (actually unneeded) shoveling of data:

```
List<?> list = (List<?>) map.get("strings");
List<String> list2 = list.stream().map(String.class::cast).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: What do you mean by "misses generic parameters, and when used bare"? And i don' t understand how to ensure that i assign only List of Strings to my variable

Comment: The concept you're looking for is called "type erasure", you should be able to find some good documentation about it online. Short version: type parameters do not exist at runtime, they are only checked at compile time, this is a technical limitation of the JVM. Generics are not a concept that existed in Java 1.0, they were added later and thus are not as integral to the design of the language as many people assume.